# Google plus's access_token integration

Tags: access-token, google-plus

I followed :
http://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth
and :
http://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get#examples

After I acquired the access token I didn't understand how to get the user's ID?  How do I use it to get the user's data?

Comment: Google docs very strange. Some steps just forgotten to be mentioned. Nothing described from A to Z. You always have to jump between 5 different docs in try to find the answer. Often nothing found. Good and reasonable question +1.

Answer (score 8):

With the access token, you can make a [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get) request with the *userId* `me`:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=1234567890
                                              ↑
```

The returned [person resource](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people#resource) has an `Id` property that contains the userId of the user:

```
{
    "kind": "plus#person",
    "id": "108189587050871927619",
    ...             ↑
}
```

Comment: work prefectly how dumb of me ...
any way i have also asked for
<https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.people.recommended>
which asks for my circles, but still i couldn't find any documentation explaining how to read them, is there a way?

Comment: There is no way to retrieve circles yet.

Comment: Iyla: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me is the only scope that works with the Google+ public data APIs right now. Other scopes will not actually provide access to any data on the Google+ APIs.